# Make HTML content area fit to viewport height?

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I just made this demo extracting out what I'm trying to accomplish:

- [Autosize Main Content Area](http://ilove4d.com/auto-size.html)

[alt text http://ilove4d.com/autosize.png](http://ilove4d.com/autosize.png)

I want the pink/yellow area to act according to these rules:

- Minimum height is the size of its content (which is variable) IF content size is smaller than viewport size
- Otherwise minimum height is such that it adjusts to fill the window.

Checking out the source to that demo, what am I missing?  I feel like this is a pretty easy case that shouldn't require javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the right html/css for a sticky footer to work, look here: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/